# RobotFrameWork standard libraries do not show up in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I installed the latest Eclipse, then robotframework 4.0.1
but in the project even te standard libraries don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Now install [RED plugin](https://github.com/nokia/RED) which supports what you want to achieve.

Marketplace: Click Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> and type into Find field "RED" Update Site: Click Help -> Install New Software -> Add and set address in Location to:

http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository